# Delete pointer to vector of char* in destructor (Not working)

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, destructor, delete-operator

I have a class that holds a few vectors, I'm not sure which method is the best but when the I call the destructor they should be deleted from memory.

HEADER:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();

    void AddString(char* text);
    void AddString(string text);

private:
    char * StringToCharPointer(string value);

    vector<char*> *pVector;
}
```

CPP File:

```
Test::Test()
{
};

Test::~Test()
{
    vector<char*>::iterator i;

    for ( i = pVector->begin() ; i < pVector->end(); i++ )
    {
        delete * i;
    }

    delete pVector;
};

char * Test::StringToCharPointer(string value)
{
    char *pChar = new char[value.length()];
    strcpy(pChar, value.c_str());

    return pChar;
};

Test::AddString(char* text)
{
    pVector->push_back(text);
};

Test::AddString(string text)
{
    pVector->push_back(StringToCharPointer(text));
};
```

so here's pretty much all the methods that I use, but what's wrong?

Comment: How you are putting data into vector? looks like those `char*`s are not allocated using `new`.

Comment: are you creating a vector with "new vector" in the constructor in the first variant and initializing it with either valid data or null pointers?

Comment: While I have vector<char*> vector I never called a constructor on it and it stored values, tried doing it for pVector by: vector<char*> vector = new vector<char*>(); pVector = &vector; not working though..

Comment: @Deukalion: Can you post some compilable come from your editor?

Comment: This works: vector<char*> vector1; vector<char*> * pVector = &vector1; but when I try to assign the same thing to the pointer in the class that I have in the class, private block it gives me an error.

Comment: Yes. It was meant to be destructor.

Comment: Whoho, pointers to vectors o/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, `i` is an iterator on the vector, it is not the pointer stored in the vector. `*i` is the pointer stored in the vector, so if you're going to delete anything it should be that.

Secondly, `delete *i` is only valid if the object pointed to by `*i` was allocated with `new`. Not `new[]`, not malloc, and it doesn't point to a string literal. Since you don't say how your data was allocated, it is not possible for us to say whether or not you are freeing it correctly.

It seems likely that you should use a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Update for updated question:

HEADER:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();

    void AddString(const string &text);
private:
    vector<string> mVector;
};
```

CPP file:

```
Test::Test()
{
};

Test::~Test()
{
};

void Test::AddString(const string &text)
{
    mVector.push_back(text);
};
```

Comment: I had a vector<std::string> earlier, changed it to char* to make the memory allocation smaller. but in my class, private block I have a couple of vector<char*> or vector<string>, I never had to call "new vector<string>()" before to be able to use push_back() on the vectors. So how am I suppose to do it?

Comment: @Deukalion: sorry, I don't understand your question. How are you supposed to do what?

Comment: I meant I never had to call new on the vector before to allocate it's size or anything. There must be someway to have a pointer to a vector of pointers and to delete it. That's pretty much what I want, my understanding how to do it is just wrong.

Comment: @Deukalion: if you want a pointer to a vector of pointers, and if you want to delete those pointers, then your destructor code is correct other than the `i` vs `*i` thing. The fact that you are getting errors is because of some problem with what you're putting into the vector, in code that you do not show.

Comment: I just edited my post and put pretty much all the code for this in post, so tell me where I forgot to put new at.

Comment: `new char[value.length()];` - this uses `new[]`, not `new`. So you have to use `delete[]`, not `delete`. The array you allocated is too short by 1, you didn't make space for the nul terminator. Also, if there are any calls to `AddString(char*)` in your program other than the one in `AddString(string)`, then you need to check how they've allocated the memory pointed to by the pointer they add to the vector.

Comment: Oh and the `pVector` member of `Test` is not initialized anywhere.

Comment: but it's a vector not an array? I use it because it's dyanmic, an array is static.

Comment: No, `pVector` is not a vector. `pVector` is a pointer. It contains an address, not the object referred to by that address. Just because you have a place that you can write an address (an envelope, say, for a real-world example) does not mean that you have an object referred to by the address (a building, in my real-world example). In your code, you don't have a vector because you never create one.

Comment: pVector is a pointer to a vector of char*, yes. but since: vector<char*> *pVector doesn't work to initialize, like vector<char*> pVector would, what am I missing?

Comment: this works: but it doesn't work with the pointer in the class as I've told you, but I can't seem to find the difference: Constructor: vector<char*> vector1; pVector = &vector1; pVector->push_back(StringToCharPointer("Test")); but if I do this in the AddString() it gives me an error, the pVector->push_back() part of the code.

Comment: `vector1` is an automatic variable, it is destroyed when the constructor returns. Sorry, without knowing why you are doing these unusual things (a pointer to vector, a vector of pointers), I can't tell for sure how to fix your code. I'm pretty sure a `vector<string>` would be best.

Comment: so, pVector = new vector<string>() and then in my method pVector->push_back(value); works but is that correct?

Comment: It's the correct way to dynamically allocate a vector, but I don't see why you want to dynamically allocate it. Just use a `vector<string>` data member in class `Test`.

Comment: As I understand it, the data in the vector doesn't get deleted when I quit. But doing it this way, then my destructor doesn't work.

Comment: In the code I have just added to my answer, everything gets destroyed when the instance of `Test` is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Your destruction code looks fine (although I guess you meant `delete *i;` in the second snippet, since otherwise, ti wouldn't have even compiled.

However, the errors you are getting indicate you put bad things in your vectors. The only `char*`s that can be inserted in the vector with such destruction code are the ones returned by `new char`. Especially, you must not insert literals (`"abc"`) or strings that are made as parts of other strings (`strtok(NULL, ":")`, `strchr(str, ':')` into it.

Comment: Or arrays allocated with `new char[some_size];`

Comment: ...but I need it to store dynamic data. Not a fixed size array.

Comment: @Deukalion: You need to read a C++ book, it is not possible to write correct C++ code by guessing. That may be possible in some languages, but C++ isn't one of them. `delete` goes with `new`, and `delete[]` goes with `new[]`.

Comment: I'm not unfamiliar with programmering, just unfamiliar with pointers and how to manage them and delete them. I just haven't used them as much. Since this works, but it doesn't work in a class scope I have no idea what's wrong: vector<char*> vector1; vector<char*> * pVector = &vector1; pVector->push_back(StringToCharPointer("test"));

Answer (score 0):

This is one obvious problem: `char *pChar = new char[value.length()];`. You are doing `new[]` but doing `delete` in destructor which invoked undefined behavior. You should use `delete[]` to delete those pointers. But using `delete[]` might give problems for `Test::AddString(char* text)` method as you can not be sure how memory for `text` is allocated i.e. using `new` or `new[]` or `malloc`. The simplest way is to use `std::vector<std::string>` as suggested by Steve Jossep.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that you should use a `std::vector<std::string>`, to shorten the wise words of  [Steve Jessop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292613/delete-pointer-to-vector-of-char-in-destructor-not-working/11292732#11292732).

To elaborate a little more: you say you want "to make the memory allocation smaller", but sounds like you're at the wrong path if you don't know pointers, and correct me if I'm wrong in guessing premature optimization (usually the case with inexperienced developers in this type of question).